# Is there a way to always keep num pad on?

Tags: numpad

I never ever turn num pad off, it's always an annoyance to turn it on once the system starts, or when I turn it off by accident.

Is there a setting to keep it on always and ignore num lock presses?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It seems that there are a number of ways to make sure it's enabled at logon are startup.  A quick search of AskUbuntu provided several, and the official help wiki lists most of them.  [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock)

Answer (score 0):

First install numlockx

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Then try adding this, to your /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc:

```
/usr/bin/numlockx on && /usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

Killing X/relogging/restart might be required for this to work.
This should permanently make num lock on.

Sources:
[Enable Numlock on Login](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock)

Comment: This didn't work. This is what it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/qCVUf7D.png

I tried with and without a dot

Comment: ok, then try xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol Num_Lock'

Answer (score -1):

Fedora 35 with gnome 41.5 go to (download tweaks app then) SETTINGS -> KEYBOARD AND MOUSE -> ADDITIONAL LAYOUT OPTIONS -> COMPATIBILITY OPTIONS -> and choose NUMERIC KEYPAD ALWAYS ENTER DIGITS.

this is basically the same for ubuntu or linux mint (look for keyboard -> additional options)

Most people have both arrow keys and a num pad so this should be the default and it's very annoying to click a number and be moved out of a form.[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu release has Gnome 42? Can you test and report back?